# How do I turn off groupLogMessages in Firefox console, not Firebug?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I know how to do this in Firbug, but want to disable the grouping (red circle with a number in it) in the regular console.  I've searched inside about:config, but couldn't find it. Is this possible?

Comment: did anyone ever find an answer? 4 years later and I still cant disable grouping console log messages.